# adding price of the products in range

Tags: magento

I have set up a shop on magento that works fine but my problem is that I want to be able to charge clients based on wight.For example

if someone chooses 6kg there should be a configured price range saying for 4-7 kg then price per kg is 2 hence total price to be 12usd or if someone enter 110.28 kg then there should be a price range defined which states that if the weight is 100-120 kg then each kg is 1.8 usd hence total price is 110.28*1.8 US

That is what i am looking for if there is a way magento can handle that please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are selling your product in 1kg units then you should be able to use tier pricing to create the above pricing structure. Your tier prices would look like:
qty = 4, price is $2
qty = 8, price is $y
...
qty = 100, price is $1.8

If you are selling in partial units (e.g. 110.28 kg) then you will need a customisation to work with per kg pricing. I'd look at commercial extensions, I'm sure there will be some available.

Comment: Apparently that does not work as it does original price of the product + tier price*qty which is very awkward.I would buy the commercial extension but I haven't come across a good one yet.

Comment: Bryton, the tier price replaces the product price when the required quantity is met. So for example if product price is $2.10 (and 1 unit is 1 kg) and you set a tier price of qty = 4 price = $2. A customer who purchases 5kg will be charged $2 per unit (i.e. kg).